# Installing different pre-requisites in bazel build depending on architecture?

Tags: bazel

I want to make a build for a C++ project so that developers can seamlessly build both in MacOS and Linux, but they need different pre-requisites.

Can I configure Bazel to run different commands depending on the architecture, as a pre-requisite to compiling C++ files?

Comment: Just to clarify, when you are saying 'run different commands' do you mean install different pre-requisites. Just trying to reconcile the question in your title with the question in the body of the text below?

Comment: The short answer to your question is yes, but short of listing every possible method for configuring Bazel, it is a little hard to answer your question with a workable example.

Comment: Correct, for example on MacOS I need to install certain packages, maybe with brew, and on linux other packages. Can you maybe provide me an hint on where to start?

Comment: Just as an additional note, that didn't feel like it belonged in the answer. While it would be possible to make a custom Bazel rule that installs system deps, this wouldn't be considered idiomatic. Instead you should document how to install system deps and then point Bazel to those system deps using a `local_repository` in your WORKSPACE.

Answer (score 2):

You certainly can, there are two approaches I will suggest.

### Approach 1 (recommended)

The best way to do this is to include all of your deps for each arch/os in your WORKSPACE file e.g.

```py
# WORKSPACE
http_archive(
   name = "foo_repo_mac",
   # ...
)

http_archive(
   name = "foo_repo_linux",
   # ...
)
```

**NOTE**: While the example here uses http_archive, this approach works with other repository rules as well e.g. local_repository (for system deps), git_repository (for git deps) etc.

Then depend on your mac/linux version os these libs using a select statement e.g.

```py
# //:BUILD.bazel
cc_library(
    name = "foo_cross_platform",
    deps = select({
        "@platforms//os:macos": ["@foo_repo_mac//:foo"],
        "@platforms//os:linux": ["@foo_repo_linux//:foo"],
    }) + ["//other:deps"],
)
```

Now what happens here is that when you build the target `//:foo_cross_platform` Bazel will first evaluate the deps in the select statement. Let's say we are running on linux it will select `"@foo_repo_linux//:foo"` as a dep. Now that Bazel knows there is a dependency in an external repository it will go ahead and download the `@foo_repo_linux` repository. But because there is no dependency in `@foo_repo_macos` it won't download/configure that dependency. So in the case of a build on Linux this will work;

```sh
bazel build //...
bazel build //:foo_cross_platform
```

However it is unlikely that running running the following on linux would work.

```
bazel build @foo_repo_macos//:foo
```

By default you can `select` based on cpu/os/distro. A full list of the configurations that are included in default Bazel are listed [here](https://github.com/bazelbuild/platforms). For more complex configurable builds take a look over the [Bazel docs on configuration](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/configurable-attributes.html).

### Approach 2 (not recommended)

If the approach 1 does not meet your needs there is a second approach that you could take and that is to write your own [repository_rule]
(https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/repository_rules.html), that uses the [repository_ctx.os](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/main/skylark/lib/repository_ctx.html#os) field with a skylark if statement. e.g.

```py
# my_custom_repository.bzl
def _my_custom_repository_rule_impl(rctx):
    if rctx.os.name == "linux":
        rctx.download_and_extract(
            url = "http//:www.my_linux_dep.com/foo",
            #...
        )
    elif rctx.os.name == "macos":
        rctx.download_and_extract(
            url = "http//:www.my_macos_dep.com/foo",
            #...
        )
    else:
        fail("No dependency for this os")

    # ... Generate a BUILD.bazel file etc.

my_custom_repository = repository_rule(_my_custom_repository_rule_impl)
```

Then add the following to your WORKSPACE;

```
# WORKSPACE
load("//:my_custom_repository.bzl", "my_custom_repository")

my_custom_repository(
    name = "foo"
)
```

Then depend on it directly in your build file (This depends on how you generate your BUILD.bazel file).

The reason I don't recommend this approach is that, repository_ctx.os.name is not particularly stable and in general the configurations using selects is far more expressive.